# how to detect a change in any excel cell in C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I am writing an excel VSTO add in, and would like to get a hold of a cell change event in a specific sheet.

how can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the `Excel.Application.SheetChange` event handler.
it basically fires whenever any cell in any sheet is changed.
you can then check the changed sheet name to filter the handler operation only to your target sheet.