# Excel to SQL remotely update to specific users

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have an SQL table on a server and I have imported it into an Excel spreadsheet, when I send this file to someone else who also has access to that server they are able to see the data but unable to refresh the data. It gives file not available error. Please let me know how can I enable those users also to refresh data at their convenience.

Second part is if any of the above users make changes in the Excel spreadsheet, can we update the SQL table dynamically? P.S there are 19 tables and each table has 20 columns so `OPENROW` is not a viable option for me. Any help or pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

use savetodb plugin for excel

http://www.savetodb.com/

create buttons in excel to load db and save changes to db

```
Dim addIn As COMAddIn
Dim addInObj As Object
Set addIn = Application.COMAddIns("SaveToDB")
Set addInObj = addIn.Object
addInObj.Save
```

I have used it multiple times, for multiple people. a word of caution, anytime you give access like this to a table in a db, you give people the ability to muck tables and dbs up. have a good backup plan handy.

you(or db admin) will need to give write access to users who will be updating these tables to the db.

Comment: one thing i forgot, you will have to install the add-in for each user on each PC - not terrible, but some GP's dont allow this for the normal users to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to update records in SQL Server based on Excel you are going to be disappointed. What you want is to create an ADP project Or MDB application using MS Access. See here: [Pros and Cons of Access Data Project (MS Access front end with SQL Server Backend)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500519/pros-and-cons-of-access-data-project-ms-access-front-end-with-sql-server-backen)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, we are not given access to MS Access. we need to work around Excel.

Comment: Then you are going to be able to allow other users to refresh it, but pushing changes back into SQL will not be do-able.

To allow other users to refresh your file, make sure: 1. They are using a vaid username/password. If you are using Windows authentication, make sure the DB Admin has added them to the authorized list. 2. They have content enabled in Excel (it warns you when opening the file). 3. They are on the same network or VPN that you were when it worked.

Comment: it says my datasource file is missing how can I solve that issue

Comment: Got it resolved thank you :), but still waiting on updating sql table from excel.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a plugin/addin for Excel that listens to events triggered for cell edit start/end. You would need to track what tab the user is on, what cell they edit, and then send the updates to SQL through the plugin application.

I no longer have access to the source code where I did this, but if this is something you want to pursue and need help getting started, let me know and I will find some links for you with the specifics on cell events.

For now, all I have is an [MSDN link for Office addins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620922.aspx)

**Update**

I did a quick search and found these links to get you started:

- [Creating your First Excel Addin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668205.aspx)
- [Selection Changed event on Worksheet](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/85e51659-979a-4f24-b578-5b2a69ee1ad8/excel-active-cell-change-event?forum=vsto)
- [Cell edit event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6743113/1439998)

Once you have a plugin that you can track the event of cell edit, then you just need to write the logic to figure out what to update in the spread sheet.

One thing to note: Every user that will edit this spreadsheet and update the database will need to install your plugin for this solution, or really any solution, to work. There is no automated way straight in Excel to do this that I am aware of.

Comment: Can you please point me to the recommended guides for starting this part.

Comment: I added a few links for you that should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

For problem 1: Does your excel spreadsheet have macros? (I would ask in comments, but my rep is too low)

If so, you need to save as type "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook" to include the macros that you wrote.